# Display table values from same column in the same row on a ListView

Tags: c#, sqlite, listview

So I'm working on a rent management software. It's for a residential complex so the manager can register the payments made by the tenants, etc. To keep track of the month being paid, I store the year/month value in a field like this:

If it is November, 2014 -> MonthPaid = 201411 | December would be 201412

The payments are stored in a table (Payments) with a foreign key to the TenantID in another table (Rent), which also stores the number of apartament (AptID). The issue is that I'm trying to display in a ListView the payments in the corresponding ListView Column (by month). If there are no payments in a specified month (ex. April 20144), then it should show a message, for now, "Deuda" in the respective ListView Column (Abril, in this example). This is what I have so far:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNrJa.jpg

And this is the expected result:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3NPg.jpg

This is the code I'm working with right now:

```
using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(cs.connstring))
      {
           using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("select AptID,MonthPaid from Rent inner join Payments on Rent.TenantID = Payments.TenantID", conn))
      {
           conn.Open();

           using (SQLiteDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
           {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                     ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(dr["AptID"].ToString());
                     if (dr["MonthPaid"].ToString() == "20141")
                     {
                         item.SubItems.Add(dr["MonthPaid"].ToString());
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         item.SubItems.Add("Deuda");
                     }
                     if (dr["MonthPaid"].ToString() == "20142")
                     {
                         item.SubItems.Add(dr["MonthPaid"].ToString());
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         item.SubItems.Add("Deuda");
                     }
                     if (dr["MonthPaid"].ToString() == "20143")
                     {
                          item.SubItems.Add(dr["MonthPaid"].ToString());
                     }
                     else
                     {
                          item.SubItems.Add("Deuda");
                     }
                     if (dr["MonthPaid"].ToString() == "20144")
                     {
                         item.SubItems.Add(dr["MonthPaid"].ToString());
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         item.SubItems.Add("Deuda");
                     }

                     lstMesesTodos.Items.Add(item);

                 }
              }
          }
      }
```

Any suggestions would be very appreciated! And I'm sorry if what I just wrote is a bit difficult to understand, haha. I hope it's not!

Comment: you could save yourself a lot of trouble using a DataGridView instead of the listView

Comment: I actually started with a DataGridView but I couldn't even manage to get more than one record and I thought that with a ListView it would be easier in this case.